# PDODriver Exception Doctrine could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

When trying to use the pdo_mysql driver in Symfony 4 and Doctrine, and I run `$entityManager->flush();`  I'm getting `An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver`

Output:

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException:
An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

  at vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:125
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver->convertException('An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver', object(PDOException))
     (vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:184)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::wrapException(object(Driver), object(PDOException), 'An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver')
     (vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:169)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::driverException(object(Driver), object(PDOException))
     (vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:47)
```

.env file has

`DATABASE_URL=mysql://USER:PASSWORD!@HOSTNAME/DATABASE`

doctrine.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7.21'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I've ensured that my docker php-fpm container has the right modules.

```
root@644cfdc6b45b:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d# php -m | grep -i pdo
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
```

My AWS RDS instance is running MySQL 5.7.21. I'm able to create and run migrations of Entities as well so bin/console is working, but Symfony itself isn't finding the right driver. Any tips to help get this working are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Below is my UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/user", name="user")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $user = new User();
        $user->setName('Jay');
        $user->setUsername('testc');
        $user->setEmail('test@test.com');
        $user->setPassword(password_hash('testpassword', PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

        $entityManager->persist($user);

        $entityManager->flush();

        return new Response('Saved new user' . $user->getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to restart my docker containers to resolve this issue.